# Using IFTTT to check JSON content and send Email or Text Message

Tags: python, json, ifttt

I am trying to learn how to use the new WebHooks service on IFTTT, and I'm struggling to figure out how it is supposed to work.  Most of the projects I can find online seem to refer to a deprecated "maker" service, and there are very little resources for interpreting the new channel.

Let's say I want to check the value of "online" every ten minutes in the following json file: https://lichess.org/api/users/status?ids=thibault

I can write a Python script that extracts this value like so:

```
response = urlopen('https://lichess.org/api/users/status?ids=thibault')
thibault = response.read()
data = json.loads(thibault)
status = data[0]['online']
```

If the `status` is equal to "true", I would like to receive a notification via email or text message.  How do I integrate the python script and the webhooks service?  Or do I even need to use this script at all? I assume I need some kind of `cron` job that regularly runs this Python script, but how do I connect this job with IFTTT?

When I create a new applet on IFTTT I am given the ability to create a trigger with a random event name, but it's unclear what that event name corresponds to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar setup for my IFTTT webhook service.  To the best of my understanding, the answer to your question is yes, you need this script (or similar) to scrap the `online` value, and you'll probably want to do a `cron` job (my approach) or keep the script running (wouldn't be my preference).

IFTTT's webhooks a `json` of up to 3 values, which you can POST to a given event and key name.

Below is a very simple excerpt of my webhook API:

```
def push_notification(*values, **kwargs):
    # config is in json format        
    config = get_config()  
    report = {}
    IFTTT = {}

    # set default event/key if kwargs are not present
    for i in ['event', 'key']: 
        IFTTT[i] = kwargs[i] if kwargs and i in kwargs.keys() else config['IFTTT'][i]

    # unpack values received (up to 3 is accepted by IFTTT)
    for i, value in enumerate(values, 1): 
        report[f"value{i}"] = value
    if report:
        res = requests.post(f"https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{IFTTT['event']}/with/key/{IFTTT['key']}", data=report)
        # TODO: add try/except for status
        res.raise_for_status() 
        return res
    else:
        return None
```

You probably don't need all these, but my goal was to set up a versatile solution.  At the end of the day, all you really need is this line here:

`requests.post(f"https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/{key}", data={my_json_up_to_3_values})`

Where you will be placing your webhook `event` name and secret `key` value.  I stored them in a config file.  The secret key will be available once you sign up on IFTTT for the webhook service (go to your IFTTT webhook applet setting).  You can find your key with a quick help link like this: `https://maker.ifttt.com/use/{your_secret_key}`.  The event can be a default value you set on your applet, or user can choose their event name if you allow.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
if status:
    push_notification("Status is True", "From id thibault", event="PushStatus", key="MysEcR5tK3y")
```

Note: I used [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) with version 3.6+ (It's great!), but if you have a lower version, you should switch all the f-strings to [`str.format()`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: Ah!  Now I understand.  Thank you so much -- this is very instructive.  I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: You're welcome, it's just something I had set up before.  Thanks to you I've gone back to update my code a bit with what I've learned now.  I understand your frustration too well because it was hard to find a updated resource regarding the IFTTT webhook.